# Adding hotkeys for bisect

Tags: customization

I am trying to add hotkey for bisect, but i can't find this option in user interface -> input. Using search on "bisect" gives 0 results. How can i find it there?[image]

Comment: Use the answer from "atek". You can change only already assigned shortcuts In the User Preferences > Input, so thats the reason why it is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode go to tool shelf under Add-> Bisect right click on it and add shortcut a pop-up to give a selection of the key. Add the key. Go to User Preference Setting save user setting so next time it will be save.

[image]